# I have a function that returns an Object's key, however I need to access the original Object from this value: Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise, response

This is my first time posting a question.

I have the following function:

```
export function sendRequest<T>(req: RawRequest, options) {
    const start = Date.now();
    const reqOptions: CoreOptions = {
        headers: {...req.headers, ['Content-type']: 'application/json'},
        body: req.body,ִ

    };

    if (options.ignoreCertError) {
        process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0 as any;
    }

    if (options.proxy) {
        reqOptions.proxy = options.proxy;
        reqOptions.tunnel = false;
    }

    return new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => request[req.method](
        req.uri, reqOptions, (error: any, response: Response, body: any) => {
            if (error) {
                reject({
                    errorCode: error.errno ?? 'unknown',
                    errorDetails: error.syscall == 'getaddrinfo' ? 'missing vpn connection?' : error,
                });
                return;
            }
            try {
                resolve(JSON.parse(body));
            } catch (ex) {
                reject({error: ex, body});
            }
        }));
}
```

as you can see, when this Promise resolves I am returned the body from the response of the request.

However, I need to somehow access the full response so that I can access the headers.

I cannot change this function - it is used by all API calls in the project

my function where I need to access the response:

```
await <my API endpoint that uses the above function>.get({
                        <my params>
                    }).then((res) => {
                        // get the response
                        // get the headers
                        return result = <something I need from the headers>
                    });
```

I hope this makes sense, can anyone help me?

Comment: Obviously, you can't. Either redesign `sendRequest` or create a new function that returns the full response and not just its body (and rewrite `sendRequest` to be a proxy for that new one).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're returning an object of the parsed JSON body. Here are two possible options:

Define two properties, one for the body and one for the response:

```
try {
  let obj = {
    body: JSON.parse(body),
    response
  };
  resolve(obj);
} catch (ex) {
  reject({error: ex, body});
}

//access it with .response, always enumerable
```

[Define a hidden property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) inside the parsed body object (not recommended):

```
try {
  let obj = JSON.parse(body);
  Object.defineProperty(obj, '_response', {value: response});
  resolve(obj);
} catch (ex) {
  reject({error: ex, body});
}

//access it with ._response, not enumerable
```

Answer (score 0):

assume *options* is an object

```
export function sendRequest<T>(req: RawRequest, options) {
const start = Date.now();
const reqOptions: CoreOptions = {
    headers: {...req.headers, ['Content-type']: 'application/json'},
    body: req.body,ִ

};

if (options.ignoreCertError) {
    process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0 as any;
}

if (options.proxy) {
    reqOptions.proxy = options.proxy;
    reqOptions.tunnel = false;
}

return new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => request[req.method](
    req.uri, reqOptions, (error: any, response: Response, body: any) => {
        if (error) {
            reject({
                errorCode: error.errno ?? 'unknown',
                errorDetails: error.syscall == 'getaddrinfo' ? 'missing vpn connection?' : error,
            });
            return;
        }
        try {
              if ('temp_key_response' in options) {
                    resolve(response);
                } else {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(body));
                }
            
        } catch (ex) {
            reject({error: ex, body});
        }
    }));
}
```

and when u calling

```
let options = {temp_key_response:'temp'}
sendRequest(req,options);
```

Comment: I don't think `response` is a JSON string

Comment: @DadiBit I've changed the code but my point is u can set a new key: value in the options argument and return response or body depending on whether the new key: value exists or not.

Comment: It's ok, but maybe it's better a `resolve_type` option, which is either set to `body` (to return the parsed body), or `response` (to return the body). Also you might `try/catch` only the `JSON.parse` line. A small improvement can also be to resolve a returning variable (so `resolve()` is written only once).